# How to open PDF raw?

Tags: pdf, adobe

I've been wanting to see the insides of a PDF for a while, like, the raw source code of it so I can look at it. Any way of doing that?

Comment: hexeditor...? basic pdfs could be written with a text editor, more or less... pdf specs are available http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html (maybe not for free the whole stuff, though I remember years ago I've got a free legal copy from Adobe, maybe older PDF versions?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [Hex editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor). Of course, unless you know the [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (PDF, 8.6 MB), you won't recognize much.

Comment: That Adobe link points to the *supplement* to ISO 32000-1 *not* the actual spec.

Answer (score 68):

Looking at the raw code of PDFs will not serve you much unless you also have an idea about its internal structure. You should get yourself a copy of the [*official PDF reference (download PDF)*](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), and you should have read some introductionary article such as <strike>[this](http://www.gnupdf.org/Introduction_to_PDF) *[gone]* or</strike> [this](http://www.mactech.com/articles/mactech/Vol.15/15.09/PDFIntro/index.html) to begin with.

Even after such a preparation, you'll not discover much useful when staring at the raw code. Because PDFs usually will contain parts which are "filtered" (that means: compressed).

### How to look at the real PDF source behind the 'raw' binary parts

Jay Birkenbilt's [**qpdf**](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) is a very useful commandline tool (available for Linux, Mac OSX, Windows, and as source code, under the open source Artistic License), which can unpack most filtered content and re-organize the internal structure in a way that gives you much more insight into it (all objects are numerically ordered, etc.). The commandline to achieve this is:

```
 qpdf  --qdf  original.pdf  unpacked.pdf
```

Another useful and free tool (GPL licensed, but Linux-only AFAIK) to look into PDFs is of course [**PDFEdit**](http://pdfedit.cz/en/index.html). This one even comes [with a GUI](http://pdfedit.petricek.net/wiki/PDFeditScreenshots) (if you prefer that), while still allowing you access to the internal structure and "raw" PDF code.

Comment: If anyone is looking for an up-to-date link for the PDF reference, it can be found here: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf (as of today at least... ) Googling PDF32000_2008.pdf should help you find it in case it is moved again.

Answer (score 9):

If the purpose is just to look into the file, then any simple text editor will do, ex, Notepad. PDF is just a text based format, including embedded content byte streams. Raw PDF looks like this:

```
>>
/Border [0 0 0]
/Rect [121.02 332.48 363.24 343.64]
/StructParent 1321
/Subtype /Link
/Type /Annot
>>
endobj
64579 0 obj
<<
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length 5771
>>
stream
Ũn0x/�+�}�ǹ����\֛ bYO�5[��X��W��L��(�������V�A3�C���������u큋_�a��ךm2N�6�    ��A��8
�d���NQ⺢GI��G�[��)�̉Y��R�y{R����&�&�;��g�k1���ҋeTC�(W��`���*��(;�AEc<=  mnZ+��|T��v
�.��зe�aޞ��V4�b���L����k�Oj.ֿ�y�����kc|I��  ��C�0��Hf�7d�/�z���m��o��A��B��IJ�%�. 
!�%f�б���&�ޒ�4Ύ7�l�3���3`�
endstream
endobj
64580 0 obj
<<
/Border [0 0 0]
/Dest <E4AE7DD2769553EF1668>
/Rect [219 648.5 256.8 659.66]
/StructParent 1323
/Subtype /Link
/Type /Annot
>>
```

What you see are basic COS objects like name, dictionary, stream and so on. All objects are described in [PDF 32000](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf) standard, see section **7.3 Objects**.

Comment: Is there any way I can convert this text data to PDF file in Javascript?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Actually PDF data is a binary format, not a text format.  You can open it and analyze as text, but you can not just update it with anything. To update PDF you need to manipulate with binary data. To convert something to  PDF, you need to use API available in your env.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the qpdf tool conversion into postscript might be helpful.
PDF is a subset of PS. Usually its quite easy to figure out, e.g. where the labels of a graph are. You can either use pdf2ps or invoke ghostscript

```
gs -sDEVICE=pswrite some.pdf -sOutputFile=some.ps -dNOPAUSE -c quit
```

When you generate your PDFs using pdflatex you can disable compression with an option. This makes the PDF more readable.

Comment: No, PDF can't exactly be described as 'a subset of PostScript'. It's derived from PostScript yes: its graphic model is the largely the same, its language's semantics are a subset of PostScript, and some of the operators it uses have identical matches in PostScript (using shorter names). However the graphic capabilities have been largely improved and extended as compared to PostScript (fonts, color spaces, transparency, ...)

Comment: I got an error when using that command: `Unknown device: pswrite` and found that it should read `ps2write` by now. My whole command was 
`gs -sDEVICE=ps2write  -sOutputFile=some.ps -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH example.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Some more recent observations on the other answers.

Adobe keep moving about their Open Sourced copy of the 2008 standard so currently that is here https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/standards/pdfstandards/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf
The Web Archive have currently a copy here https://ia601003.us.archive.org/5/items/pdf320002008/PDF32000_2008.pdf

They should be identical 22,491,828 bytes so beware neither includes any errata.

A pdf CAN be plain mime **"text/pdf"** as perfectly ? annotated generated from a console keyboard or command line (too slow) or a batch file. I won't bore you with the [whole file](https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/demo.pdf) but it starts like this:

```
REM Start with File "Magic" Signatures for a PDF
echo %%PDF-1.0>!Fname!
echo %%âãÏÓ>>!Fname!

echo %%01) Prepare file references>>!Fname!
for %%Z in (!Fname!) do set "FZ1=%%~zZ"
echo 1 0 obj>>!Fname!
echo ^<^</Names^<^</Dests 2 0 R^>^>/Outlines 3 0 R>>/PageLayout/OneColumn/PageMode/UseOutlines>>!Fname!

REM ToDo add files
REM /Lang (ga-IE)/MarkInfo^<^</Marked true^>^>/Names ^<^<^/EmbeddedFiles [(file.ext) 3 0 R]^>^>>>!Fname!

echo /Pages 4 0 R/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences^<^</DisplayDocTitle true^>^>^>^>>>!Fname!
echo endobj>>!Fname!

echo %%02) Prepare Named Destinations>>!Fname!
```

Thus the annotated RAW PDF (note I had edited the order in the [cmd file](https://github.com/GitHubRulesOK/MyNotes/raw/master/MAKE-PDF.cmd) in preparation for an XMP data section, so not identical) could look like :-

```
%PDF-1.3 
%âãÏÓ
%01) Prepare file references
1 0 obj
<</Lang(ga-IE)/Names<</Dests 3 0 R>>/Outlines 4 0 R/PageLayout/OneColumn/PageMode/UseOutlines
/PageLabels<</Nums[0<</S/A>>]>>/Pages 5 0 R/Type/Catalog/ViewerPreferences<</DisplayDocTitle true>>>>
endobj
%02) Reserved for big meta data
2 0 obj
<< >>
endobj
%03) Prepare Named Destinations
3 0 obj
<</Names [(Page1) [6 0 R /XYZ 0 792 null] (QRCode) [6 0 R /XYZ 25.0 317.0 1]]>>
endobj
%04) Prepare Outline / Bookmarks
...
...
```

Many suggestions by others for decompress binary application/PDF into text/PDF and some may be a hybrid thus still have binarized application text.

The 3 most common designed for the task are qpdf (already mentioned, but uses a hybrid QDF) PDFtk (uncompress) and Mutool (different CLI options), that's the one I play with most, as it's easy in GL GUI to change the output settings. The output can be modified in MS Notepad, whilst previewing result.

So **any text editing script can write or edit a PDF** even with graphics. And several applications can convert RAW "binary" PDF into RAW "textual" PDF. However never attempt to edit PDF whilst temporarily in its textual base64 RePrEx (possible, but totally impractical)

[image]