# How can I sanitize PHP data for writing to PDF file?

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm having a lot of issues writing database results to a PDF using FPDF, it seems there is either unsupported data or characters or ~something~ in the data being returned from the database.

- the PDF file gets written and downloaded with no errors, but occasuionally I get a page that looks like:

[image]

The asterisks are missing pages. now, I'm trying to sanitize the data by running each item through a function:

```
public function cleanPDFData($data){

        $data = utf8_decode($data);
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $data);

        return $data;

    }
```

But I am still getting broken pages.

- If I replace the query results with a string, the PDF is generated perfectly [i.e. return "test"; ] the error is in the data itself
- if I view the record in the database, nothing appears out of sorts, correct data types, no funny characters, no missing data. I don't know what else to look for.
- if I start deleting records before the blank pages, the PDF will again generate itself perfectly.
- no errors are thrown

I am out of ideas, my best guess is that my php script is trying to pass some sort of unsupported character or data to the FPDF - but I have no idea what it might be!

here is the actual PDF : [sample-pdf.pdf](http://www.globalstainlessauctions.com/sample-pdf.pdf)

**UPDATE**

ok  - I think I found part of the problem, here is the updated cleaning function:

```
public function cleanPDFData($data){

        if(strlen($data) <= 0){$data = '-';}

        $data = trim($data);
        $data = str_replace('/', '-', $data);
        $data = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $data);
        $data = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $data);

        return $data;

    }
```

So once the "/" characters are removed, the PDF will generate properly, but now I am left without the [sometimes] needed slashes (/). 
How can I generate the PDF ensuring that all the special characters are correctly displayed?

Comment: Do you get any errors from FPDF? There should be some information from the lib that shows where the problem is exactly. Data in the screens seems simple so it's even wierder.

Comment: Have you tried viewing the PDF source? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562235/how-to-open-pdf-raw

Comment: @Lukas - no errors are thrown at all [by anything]

Comment: @ymas ... hmm, I can try, but I'm not sure what that's gonna get me. Don't know anything about the internals of a PDF.

Comment: @SeanKimball errors might be logged to apache log file, check them too.

Comment: @lukas, nope, been tailing that log hoping for something.

Comment: @SeanKimball it'll provide a clue about what is causing the error.  The PDF reference is not particularly complex.  If possible, can you provide a link to a problematic PDF?

Comment: sure can: www.globalstainlessauctions.com/sample-pdf.pdf

Comment: @SeanKimball can you please turn the compression off?  I'm going to uncompress the document myself, but it would be great if you could do that too.

Comment: here is a complete file with compression off [I think] I added $pdf->setCompression('false'); [I think that will do it?]  globalstainlessauctions.com/746-globalstainless-search-results.pdf

Comment: There are really syntax errors in the pages content streams. You will see tokens like `B0.54` or `331.5Q` or `(6120 331.5Q` in them. Are you using the latest version of FPDF? If yes, we would need some more code. Are you using any special extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem turned out to be compression.

You can disable compression via:

```
$pdf->setCompression(false);
```

Thanks to Olivier on the FPDF forums.