# Upload file to Zapier Webhook

Tags: zapier

Is uploading files to a zapier webhook via POST allowed?

I didn't manage to get it working. In my form, I have some text inputs (name, email etc), and one `<input type="file" name="cv" />`. Here's my AJAX code:

```
$('#__formID__').submit(function(e) {

  var data = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  console.log(data.get('cv'));

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://hooks.zapier.com/hooks/catch/someid/someid/',
    type: 'POST',

    // Form data
    data: data,
    // Tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
    // You *must* include these options!
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
  });
});
```

The file (cv) does get sent, I see the correct console.log above, and I see this in the Request Payload (in Chrome console):

```
------WebKitFormBoundary4sbU6QlU3xl7ox2f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

John Doe
------WebKitFormBoundary4sbU6QlU3xl7ox2f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="university"

BLABLABLA
------WebKitFormBoundary4sbU6QlU3xl7ox2f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

john.doe@gmail.com
------WebKitFormBoundary4sbU6QlU3xl7ox2f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="skype"

johndoe
------WebKitFormBoundary4sbU6QlU3xl7ox2f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="skills"

dsaf
------WebKitFormBoundary4sbU6QlU3xl7ox2f
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cv"; filename="cv-fr.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf


------WebKitFormBoundary4sbU6QlU3xl7ox2f--
```

But on the Zapier side, I receive every attribute except the `cv` one:

```
name:   John Doe
university: BLABLABLA
skills: dsaf
skype:  johndoe
email:  john.doe@gmail.com
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: Following up here as well.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that [Zapier accepts raw data for the request](https://cdn.zapier.com/storage/photos/31e3196fcee888dba1fc7f8810ccaeb0.png): "Place raw data for the request here. Could be JSON, XML, etc."

To my understanding, [PDF is not considered as raw data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562235/how-to-open-pdf-raw). Your case tends to verify this hypothesis as only your strings pass.